# How to have background image that is centered/covering the div, but with padding

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position, background-size

I have the following HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
      }

      body > header {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
      }

      header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      header > section {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex: 1;
      }

      header > section > figure {
        flex: 1;
        background: red;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      header > h1 {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        background: black;
        color: white;
      }

      header > section > figure > img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background: green;
      }

      header > section > aside {
        width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        background: yellow;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <section>
        <figure>
          <img/>
        </figure>
        <aside>
          <img/>
        </aside>
      </section>

      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have the image be centered with padding of at least 50px in every screen size and orientation. That's pretty much it. Can't figure it out.

For example, the green area/image in the example should show an image that is not stretched, that has some padding around it so you can see the full red figure around it.

Comment: Can you make it clearer how you want the end result to look?

Comment: Use `background-size: cover` for the image and wrap it in a 50px padded container.

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser that doesn't work, it chops off the edges of the nested image.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your problem, but doesn't adding `padding: 50px;` to your `section` tag work? Don't change the background-size, only the padding.

Comment: I changed the question slightly so it can use image tag b/c it doesn't seem possible with CSS only.

Comment: `<div style="padding:50px"><div style="background: ............."></div></div>` This is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Green area ????